# Write a Java program that generates five questions and reports the number of the correct answers after a student answers all five questions

Tags: java

I'm new at java, and i am trying to write a code that displays the number of questions they got right, not that they got each one right. When i try to run it, i can't make it display the number of questions they got right. For example, i want it to say "You got 4 out of 5 questions correct!", depending on how many they got right. This is what i have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Addition {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int count = 0;
      while (count < 5){
         int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
         int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
         System.out.println("What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + "?");
         count++;
         int answer = number1 + number2;
         int guess = sc.nextInt();
         boolean correct = guess == answer;
         if (guess == answer){
         }      
         System.out.println("You got " + correct + " correct");
      }     
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slight change required in your logic.

```
int correctAnswer = 0; // this is a new variable you have to introduce before  while (count < 5){

if (guess == answer){
    correctAnswer++;
}

// This line should be outside of while loop as well..
System.out.println("You got " + correctAnswer + " out of " + count + " questions correct");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:
(1) no count of correct answers;
(2) no print after you're done.
You *do* have a print while the test is in progress, but that's not when you said you want to print.  Try these two changes: count inside the if statement and print *after* the loop,.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 5){
        ... 
        boolean correct = guess == answer;
        if (guess == answer){
             correct++;
        }
    }       
    System.out.println("You got " + correct + " out of " + count " questions correct");
}
```